# Getting all the children of the root node

Tags: sql, sql-server, tree, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a database structure like

```
------------------------------------------
NodeId  |   Parent
-----------------------------------------
1           0
2           0
3           1
4           1
5           2
6           2    
7           3
8           3
9           4
10          4
11          5
12          5
13          6
```

Forming a tree structure like

```
1
->3
  -->7
  -->8
->4
  -->9
  -->10
2
->5
  -->11
  -->12
->6
  -->13
```

Now the user can enter any node id

to retrieve

- all the nodes under that nodeid

union

- all the nodes under the root node of the node id

For example:
if user click on Node id 1,
Result should be (This I'm able to achieve with the CTE)

```
1 0
3 1
4 1
7 3
8 3
9 4
10 4
```

But if User click on any mid node like 4
Result should be

```
4 1
9 4
10 4
```

Union (all the nodes under root Parent of the node)
Root parent of the node 4 = 1
so result should be

```
1 0 
3 1
4 1 (Should be excluded as comes under first query)
7 3
8 3
9 4 (Should be excluded as comes under first query)
10 4 (Should be excluded as comes under first query)
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
declare @Node int;
Set @node=1
with [CTE] As
(
  Select [nodeid], [Parent]
  from [NodeTable]
  where [nodeid]=@nodeid

  union

  Select [
  from [Nodetable] [NT]
    inner join [CTE] on [CTE].[nodeid]=[NT].[Nodeid]
)

Select * from [CTE]
```

Comment: Please use only the relevant version tag. Is it 2008-r2 or 2012?  Also, Please read the first paragraph of the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can first retrieve the `RootId` of the specified node with the first `CTE` and then use `CTE2` to retrieved all the children of the retrieved `RootId`:

```
    declare @node int;
Set @node=4;
with [CTE] As
(
  Select [nodeid] NodeId, [Parent] Parent
  from [NodeTable]
  where [nodeid]=@node

  union all

  Select [NT].[nodeid] ni, [NT].[Parent] pi
  from [Nodetable] [NT]
    inner join [CTE] 
    on  [CTE].Parent=[NT].NodeId
), [CTE2] As
(
  Select [nodeid] NodeId, [Parent] Parent
  from [NodeTable]
  where [nodeid]= (select top 1 NodeId from CTE order by NodeId)

  union all

  Select [NT].[nodeid] ni, [NT].[Parent] pi
  from [Nodetable] [NT]
    inner join [CTE2] 
    on [CTE2].NodeId=[NT].Parent
)


Select * from [CTE2]
order by NodeId
```

Also, if you want to exclude the node itself and its children, you can add `CTE3` retrieving the node children and use except to get to the desired output:

```
declare @node int;
Set @node=4;
with [CTE] As
(
  Select [nodeid] NodeId, [Parent] Parent
  from [NodeTable]
  where [nodeid]=@node

  union all

  Select [NT].[nodeid] ni, [NT].[Parent] pi
  from [Nodetable] [NT]
    inner join [CTE] 
    on  [CTE].Parent=[NT].NodeId
), [CTE2] As
(
  Select [nodeid] NodeId, [Parent] Parent
  from [NodeTable]
  where [nodeid]= (select top 1 NodeId from CTE order by NodeId)

  union all

  Select [NT].[nodeid] ni, [NT].[Parent] pi
  from [Nodetable] [NT]
    inner join [CTE2] 
    on [CTE2].NodeId=[NT].Parent
), [CTE3] As
(
  Select [nodeid] NodeId, [Parent] Parent
  from [NodeTable]
  where [nodeid]=@node

  union all

  Select [NT].[nodeid] ni, [NT].[Parent] pi
  from [Nodetable] [NT]
    inner join [CTE3] 
    on  [CTE3].NodeId = [NT].Parent
)

Select * from [CTE2]
except
Select * from [CTE3]
order by NodeId
```

Comment: Isn't the root level of all nodes equal to 1?

Comment: Yes I missed that. Answer was updated. The exclusion part was also added.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use a recursive cte that will also keep the root node of every recursion, and then query this cte based on the root of the desired node.

First, create and populate sample table: (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    NodeId int,
    Parent int
);

INSERT INTO @T (NodeId, Parent) VALUES
(1 , 0),
    (3 , 1),
        (7 , 3),
        (8 , 3),
    (4 , 1),
        (9 , 4),
        (10, 4),

(2 , 0),
    (5 , 2),
        (11, 5),
        (12, 5),
    (6 , 2),
        (13, 6);
```

The recursive cte:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT NodeId, Parent, NodeId As Root
    FROM @T
    WHERE Parent = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.NodeId, t.Parent, Root
    FROM @T As t
    JOIN CTE 
        ON t.Parent = CTE.NodeId
)
```

The query:

```
SELECT NodeId, Parent
FROM CTE
WHERE Root = (SELECT Root FROM CTE WHERE NodeId = 4)
```

Results:

```
NodeId Parent
1       0
3       1
4       1
9       4
10      4
7       3
8       3
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](https://rextester.com/FOXX61239)

Comment: Zohar, its ok, but how should i identify "direct nodes" and "other nodes of the root Node", Thanks for help

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the exact result set you want to get?